# How to remove sort order number from column header when using multiple sort

Tags: angular, ag-grid

```
 - https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/row-sorting/#multi-column-sorting
 - https://plnkr.co/edit/9PYpbplbwC9qoUWw
```

On the above example, You can see when using The grid sorts by Country then Athlete by default, It header text "Athlete 2" and "Country 1".

My need is to get rid of this "2" from  "Athlete 2" & "1" from "Country 1" when multiple sort are used

Comment: We cannot access the link. Please find a way to share the code in another way. Preferably, copy paste it here and, if you can, please provide a working Stackblitz

Comment: Please share some relevant code.

Comment: @Arnuaud shared sample

Comment: @Joosep.P  shared sample

Comment: Empty plunker...